# How do I get my wordpress plugin to add rewrite rules to the .htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, plugins

I have been working with WP for years but this is my first time working on a plugin that needs new rewrite rules.

I have a single rule I need to add to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^loan-application/step([0-9])|(stepsuccess)/?$ index.php?pagename=loan-application&step=$1 [NC,L]
```

How do I make the plugin add this to the file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To open and add that:

```
$file = fopen(".htacces",a+);
fwrite( $file, "RewriteRule ^loan-application/step([0-9])|(stepsuccess)/?$ index.php?pagename=loan-application&step=$1 [NC,L]");
```

Only take care where is the file having this function, and where is .htaccess.

fopen - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
fwrite - http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: You need to add those rules to the beginning of the wordpress block, otherwise the default routing rules will supercede whatever you add

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you should be modifying .htaccess directly.  There's a WordPress class to manage rewrite rules which has the ability to overwrite all or part of the WordPress .htaccess (likely overwriting any changes you have made):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Indeed, I believe you should actually be using this class to achieve your goal.  Unfortunately, I stumbled on this question while researching these rules for the first time so I'm not (yet) able to provide any further detail.  The best guide I've found (so far) is:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/